# Dovecot authenticate against Active directory cant send to users that was in aliases

Tags: active-directory, sendmail, dovecot

I use Dovecot and sendmail on centos 6, it authenticates against my Server 2012 R2 Domain. I can log in with all user accounts but I have problems with two users sales and info that was getting send to root.

I removed them from /etc/aliases and ran newaliases whic solved the mail going to root but now those two emails give user unknown errors when I mail them.

The Username for sales in the AD is Sales and email is sales@domain.com when I email it tells me user does not exist. 
info username in AD is Operations and email is info@domain.com the email to info@domain.com gets send but then bounces back user unknown

```
[root@sogo domain.com]# cat /etc/dovecot-ldap.conf
hosts = CB2012r2DC:3268
dn = cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=cb,dc=local
dnpass = password
ldap_version = 3
base = dc=cb,dc=local
scope = subtree
auth_bind = yes
user_attrs = sAMAccountName=user
user_filter = (&(ObjectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=%u))
pass_filter = (&(ObjectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=%u))
pass_attrs = sAMAccountName=user

[root@sogo dovecot]# cat dovecot.conf
disable_plaintext_auth = no
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot_lda.log
log_path = /var/log/dovecot_lda.log
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_gid = 500
mail_location = maildir:/home/vhostmail/domain.com/%u/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_uid = 500
mail_debug = yes
mail_plugins = acl
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date
#auth_verbose = yes
#auth_debug = yes
#auth_debug_passwords = yes

passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot-ldap.conf
  driver = ldap
}
protocols = imap pop3 sieve
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-client {
    mode = 0600
  }
  unix_listener auth-master {
    group = vhostmail
    mode = 0600
    user = vhostmail
  }
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  user = dovecot
}


protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_acl
}


service pop3-login {
  user = dovecot
#  mail_plugins = acl imap_acl
}
ssl = no
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot-ldap.conf
  driver = ldap
}
protocol lda {
  auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
  hostname = localhost
  mail_debug = yes
  info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot_lda.log
  log_path = /var/log/dovecot_lda.log
  mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot
  mail_plugins = sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster@domain.com
  sendmail_path = /usr/lib/sendmail

}

service managesieve-login {
  user = dovecot
  inet_listener sieve {
  port = 4190
}

protocol sieve {
#managesieve_logout_format = bytes=%i/%o
#managesieve_implementation_string = Dovecot Pigeonhole
#managesieve_implementation_string = Cyrus timsieved v2.2.13



}


}
plugin {
  # Used by both the Sieve plugin and the ManageSieve protocol
  sieve = /home/vhostmail/domain.com/%u/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = /home/vhostmail/domain.com/%u/sieve

}
```

bounced mail only if you send to info, sales never gets one

```
The original message was received at Sat, 24 Sep 2016 16:20:22 +0200
from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]

  ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<info@domain.com>
    (reason: User unknown)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
550 5.1.1 <info@domain.com>... User unknown



Reporting-MTA: dns; sogo.domain.com
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost.localdomain
Arrival-Date: Sat, 24 Sep 2016 16:20:22 +0200

Final-Recipient: RFC822; info@domain.com
X-Actual-Recipient: RFC822; info@sogo.domain.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Unix; 67
Last-Attempt-Date: Sat, 24 Sep 2016 16:20:23 +0200
```

I send one email from info@domain.com to info@domain.com and one from sales@domain.com to sales@domain.com

here is the mail logs

```
Sep 24 19:08:19 sogo sendmail[1579]: u8OH8IGB001579: from=     <info@domain.com>, size=772, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<269-57e6b300-f-   26620080@66074461>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain   [127.0.0.1]
Sep 24 19:08:20 sogo sendmail[1581]: u8OH8IGB001579: to=  <info@domain.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=dovecot,   pri=120772, relay=dovecot, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Sep 24 19:08:20 sogo sendmail[1581]: u8OH8IGB001579: u8OH8KGB001581: DSN:  User unknown
Sep 24 19:08:20 sogo sendmail[1581]: u8OH8KGB001581: to= <info@domain.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=dovecot,  pri=32017, relay=dovecot, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Sep 24 19:08:21 sogo sendmail[1581]: u8OH8KGB001581: u8OH8KGC001581: return  to sender: User unknown
Sep 24 19:08:23 sogo sendmail[1581]: u8OH8KGC001581: to=postmaste@somedomain.com,   delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=33041,   relay=mail.mail.com. [x.x.x.x], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent   (u8OH8MqY017480 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 24 19:10:23 sogo sendmail[1604]: u8OHAMNp001604:   <sales@domain.com>... User unknown
Sep 24 19:10:23 sogo sendmail[1604]: u8OHAMNp001604: from=  <sales@domain.com>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP,   daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: Please add the bounce messages and log output for sendmail/dovecot, otherwise the issue can hardly be analyzed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so both my problems were in /etc/mail/virtusertable
I had a entry there for sales that should not have been there

```
sales@domain.com  sales
```

then for info I should have had a entry as the username in AD is not same as the email address

```
info@domain.com    operations@domain.com
```

Problem solved happy days!